# C++ ofstream flush sometimes loses trailing nulls

Tags: c++, flush

I'm getting puzzling file output when using flush with ofstream on Windows7 with VC++ 2010 professional.

Essentially, I want to serialise some values, and check them while debugging. Why does the file contain incorrectly serialised values until the INT_MAX max is written? Notice how the unsigned int values appear to be truncated (only first two bytes), then the missing bytes reappear *after* the INT_MAX value gets written. Very weird. I'm checking the file in a separate HEX editor during breakpoints.

This seems to be a problem while in debugging or in release mode, and only seems to affect values that end with a pair of 00 (NULL).

```
ofstream myStream("testfile.txt", ios::out | ios::binary);

unsigned int val = 3;   
myStream.write((char *) &val, 4);
myStream.flush(); 
// breakpoint, check file HEX: 03 00
//                                   ^^ ^^ missing values


val = 4;
myStream.write((char *) &val, 4);
myStream.flush();  
// breakpoint check file HEX: 03 00 04 00
//                                        ^^ ^^ missing values

val = INT_MAX;
myStream.write((char *) &val, 4);
myStream.flush();  
// breakpoint check file HEX: 03 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 FF FF FF 7F
//                                  ^^ ^^       ^^ ^^              reappeared values
```

I've tried writing to a Network disk, calling _commit and fflush on the FileHandle and attempted to link commode.obj (although I'm not at all sure the linking actually happened). None of these things helped. The best I could do for now is to write out INT_MAX at the start of the serialisation to "initialise" the thing, becasue subsequent values are then written correctly.

Comment: Related: I'm curious to know why you're not using an actual `uint32_t` for this and avoiding the dice-roll that `unsigned int` is 32bits long.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. You're probably right, should use uint32_t. I thought it was sneaky for the program to go back and insert values in the file after flushing.